# How can i grab the matched regex pattern in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this code and its not working

```
import re
mystring = "This is my test the string to match the stuff"    
p = re.compile(" the ")
```

Now I want to able to put the first match found in `var1` and second match in `var2`

Comment: have you read the [python re documentation yet](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: i think u r right , i have to study the whole page. i am doing that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: strs= "This is my test the string to match the stuff"

In [5]: p = re.compile(" the ")

In [6]: re.findall(p,strs)
Out[6]: [' the ', ' the ']

In [7]: var1,var2=re.findall(p,strs)

In [8]: var1,var2
Out[8]: (' the ', ' the ')
```

In case the number of matches returned are more than 2, then you've slice the list first.

```
var1,var2=[' the ', ' the ',' the '][:2]
```

On python 3.x you can take the advantage of the `*` to grab the rest of the elements in a list:

```
In [2]: var1,var2,*extras=[' the ', ' the ','foo','bar']

In [3]: var1
Out[3]: ' the '

In [4]: var2
Out[4]: ' the '

In [5]: extras             #rest of the elements are stored in extras
Out[5]: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: @user55711 Glad that helped, feel free to accept the answer when the time limit is over.